# Oval shaped images in ASP.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, drawing, shapes

I need to generate oval shaped images on ASP.Net pages. Either I need to resize it to oval shape when it's being uploaded or show it as oval shape on the fly.

Have a look at cac.mysiteportal.com to get an overview of what I am trying to achieve. I am talking about the 3 oval shaped image on the right hand side.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Comment: @Kunal i dont think there is oval crop image resizer.... Lets wait for answers...

Comment: Isn't there any ways to use the Graphics Libraries which comes along with Asp.Net?

Answer (score 0):

You can [crop images with oval clip regions using WIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746710.aspx).
You can use [WIC in ASP.Net](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/01/21/server-side-resizing-with-wpf-now-with-jpg.aspx).
However, it is not supported by MS.
Neither using System.Drawing, I should add.